# String to Float Unity Console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I'm trying to take the data I have in string format that is already being read out in my unity console into a float so I can put it through an if statement. However, unity is telling me I can't use "<" on a double or bool value. I'm not sure what changes I would need to make to get the if statement to read the value (possibly another data type?). Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class HeaterRead : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
 {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\labom\Documents\Work Files\Heater_Main_Output.csv"))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            listA.Add(values[2]);
            listB.Add(values[3]);
            Debug.Log(values[2].ToString() + "        " + values[3].ToString());
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        float TempVal = float.Parse(listB[3]);

        if (TempVal < 300)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }

        if (300 <= TempVal < 308.4)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: `if (300 <= TempVal < 308.4)` what are you trying to do here; this is your issue. Maybe something like `if (300 <= TempVal && TempVal < 308.4)`, really not sure what you want here?

Comment: If you want to say that you are testing to see that TempVal is greater than or equal to 300 and less than 308.4, then use: `if (300.0f <= TempVal && TempVal < 308.4f)`.  The important part is the `&&`.  The `f`s at the end of the literals makes those values literal floats (otherwise, everything gets converted to `double` which you don't need)

Comment: Depending on how sure you are about the strings containing your floats, you may want to use `float.TryParse` rather than `float.Parse`.  The latter will throw an exception on a parse failure, the former gives you a true/false return that you can test

Comment: FYI, you have two `ReadLine` statements in your loop, so i think you're only reading every other line.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now!

Answer (score -1):

In the condition: `if (300 <= TempVal < 308.4)`, what's happening is that `300 <= TempVal` is evaluated first (which produces a `bool` value of `true` or `false`), and then the result of that value is used in the next comparison, `true < 308.4`, which is giving you the error *"Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'"*.

To fix this, you need to break the check into two different statements:

```
if (300 <= TempVal && TempVal < 308.4)
```